# Find a table to merge with

Tags: google-fusion-tables

In the web application of google fusion tables there is an option "find a table to merge with" which searches for the most similar tables for the specific table.
Is there an option to do it with the api as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the service this feature uses is only accessible from the Fusion Tables app.